# Input search field created by React works incorrectly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, input, state

Using React, I created a search input and I expect the persons to be displayed according to my search value. This is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function FilterPerson() {

    const [persons, setPersons] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setPersons([
            { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 27 },
            { firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe', age: 25 },
            { firstName: 'Baby', lastName: 'Doe', age: 21 },
        ]);
    }, []);

    const toDisplay = persons.map((person) => {
        return (
            <div key={person.firstName}>
                {person.firstName}, {person.lastName}, {person.age}
            </div>
        );
    });

    const onChangedHandler = (value) => {
        setPersons(persons.filter((person) => {
            return person.firstName.includes(value)
        }));
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" onChange={(event) => onChangedHandler(event.target.value)} />
            {toDisplay}
        </div>
    );
};

export default FilterPerson;
```

This is what I see on the screen:
[image]

Then, I type a capital J in the field, like this:
[image]

Only **J**ohn and **J**ane are displayed. The result looks good.

However, when I delete the capital J from the field, Baby Doe should show up, but it doesn't:
[image]

Moreover, when I type a capital B again, everything disappear:
[image]

From now, it doesn't matter what I type in the search field, nothing show up anymore.

Can anyone help me on this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing the `persons` data when you start writing. I've updated your code so that it appends the filtered persons out to another array.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function FilterPerson() {

    const [persons, setPersons] = useState([]);
    const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setPersons([
            { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 27 },
            { firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe', age: 25 },
            { firstName: 'Baby', lastName: 'Doe', age: 21 },
        ]);
    }, []);

    const toDisplay = filtered.map((person) => {
        return (
            <div key={person.firstName}>
                {person.firstName}, {person.lastName}, {person.age}
            </div>
        );
    });

    const onChangedHandler = (value) => {
        setFiltered(persons.filter((person) => {
            return person.firstName.includes(value)
        }));
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" onChange={(event) => onChangedHandler(event.target.value)} />
            {toDisplay}
        </div>
    );
};

export default FilterPerson;
```

**Edit**: [Kirankumar Ambati](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63159725/4240137)'s answer below will be far more efficient, especially if the `persons` array becomes large.

Comment: Hi Reece, this works for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi @Dimisizz, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

**Baby Doe** is removed from `persons` Array. Try to use 2 different `states`. Keep all persons in one `array` and keep filtered users in another `array`

Comment: Hi, I created the another state and keep filtering in it. It works. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I updated your code to have a `searchTerm` which handles the filter input and get `persons` as per the `searchTerm`.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

    function FilterPerson() {

    const [persons, setPersons] = useState([]);
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        setPersons([
            { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 27 },
            { firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe', age: 25 },
            { firstName: 'Baby', lastName: 'Doe', age: 21 },
        ].filter(person => {
            if(searchTerm === "") {
                return person;
            }            
            
            return person.firstName.includes(searchTerm);
        }));
    }, [searchTerm]);

    const toDisplay = persons.map((person) => {
        return (
            <div key={person.firstName}>
                {person.firstName}, {person.lastName}, {person.age}
            </div>
        );
    });

    const onChangedHandler = (value) => {
        setSearchTerm(value);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" onChange={(event) => onChangedHandler(event.target.value)} />
            {toDisplay}
        </div>
    );
};`

export default FilterPerson;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, as soon as you type J, you changed the content of persons array. So that makes sense to me